# How to build an XLL addin for Excel on macOS via Xcode/VC for mac?

Tags: excel, xcode, macos, visual-studio, xll

I have build several xll addin for Excel on windows system. I wonder how to build a xll addin on macOS for Excel for macOS?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The XLL interface is not supported by Mac Excel so it is not possible. Mac Excel supports VBA/COM Addins and the new JS API Office Addins.

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you very much!